# How to force authentication challenging for every request in REST?

Tags: java, rest, tomcat, authentication, jersey

My understanding is that a RESTful service should be totally stateless. Every time I invoke the service, I must pass all the information it needs to operate properly.

However, when it comes to authentication I get rather confused about how this should work, particularly in terms of session management.

I am using basic authentication and the first time I make a request, the client gets challenged (or I can pass the authentication information in the header from the beginning). But once the user has been authenticated, the server will not challenge this client anymore as long as the session is alive.

This means that I need to provide some mechanism for the current user to logout (terminate his/her session).

It would look like the right way of doing this would be to change my configuration somehow so that every request is challenged for authentication, but I have no clue how this plays with session management.

- Am I supposed to invalidate the session manually after every request?
- Or is there way to force the clients to be challenged every time a request is made?

You can find lots of questions out there about security with REST, and even books about how to implement different models of authentication. But I have not found a good answer on how to deal with session management, logging in and out. So either I am doing something wrong or I am misunderstanding something important here.

I would appreciate any thoughts or guidance on how this should be properly handled.

I am using Jersey 2.4 with Tomcat 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're authenticating with HTTP Basic, the client is challenged the first time only because the Authorization header isn't being sent from the client. Once it's sent and the server sends something other than a 401, the client caches those credentials and re-sends them with every request.

You shouldn't create sessions in a stateless app, not only because they aren't used, but because they require overhead to manage (even empty ones). The servlet architecture, however, cannot prevent code from creating sessions, such as when the code calls either `httpServletRequest.getSession()` or `httpServletRequest.getSession(true)`. So you need to ensure that you don't use any code (or frameworks) that do this.

Interestingly enough, Tomcat will still generate a JSESSIONID cookie for the client to use, and under most configurations of the container, you can't turn this off. However, if sessions aren't created, the cookie is essentially ignored (and a new JSESSIONID cookie will be generated on every request).

And, because the app is stateless, there is no concept of login or logout. All authentication is done per request.

Note that, depending on your particular app, pragmatism may trump pure RESTfulness. There are cases where "a little bit" of server state is really the only way to provide some types of security to the app (such as cross-site request forgery, anything with nonces, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing a RESTful webservice you shouldn't handle sessions.
The first time you connect to the API you need to pass the authentication check in order to obtain an authentication key. 
This key is how your API will identify its users.

You shouldn't invalidate the session and you shouldn't force your users to re-authenticate.

Comment: Can you please elaborate in what you mean by "authentication key"?

Comment: By authentication key I mean a key that is unique to the user of your webservice. The first time a user uses your API he will have to pass the authentication check. Passing this check your webservice should generate a unique key that will be sent to the user. In this way you ensure that the user doesn't send his credentials in plaintext everytime he makes a request.